# How do I get rid of labels in django Form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

I have dealt with only ModelForm previously, so it is my first time using Form.
I'd like to get rid of labels from my form, however, how I get rid of labels in ModelForm does not seem to work with Form.

Here is my code:
**forms.py**

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

    labels = {
        'email': '',
        'password': ''
    }
    widgets = {
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'login_input', 'placeholder': 'Email'}),
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'login_input', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
    }
```

It seemed like a simple problem but it turned out I could not get what I wanted from the official django document or Google. I'd be really appreciated if you could help me solving it.

Comment: In the template itself, you don't need to use `{{ form }}`. You can format the form manually doing `{{ form.email }}` for example to just render the `email` input. For two fields, that should be practical.

Comment: Also, I believe `labels` and `widgets` belong in a `Meta` subclass, not in the form class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate) mentioned in the above comment that you can directly use `{{form.email}}` which would only render input tag instead of label tag.

To remove the label you should use inline labels not labels dict as they are defined in `Meta` class, so:

```py
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="")
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="")
```

You can also define inline `widegts`.

Then you can use `{{form}}` and won't see labels in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but this is what I did:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    template_name_label = None
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).